# RMI call with Remote interface at ejb 3 in glassfish

Tags: rest, glassfish, weblogic, ejb-3.1

I have some problem with this code , when i am trying to call the Remote interface , that is deploy in other server (Weblogic) .

this is my client :

```
package service;

import java.util.*;
import javax.ejb.*;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
@Path("/")
@Stateless


public class GestionPersonnel {
  Context ctx;


   @GET
   @Produces("application/json")
   @Path("requete")
public  void test() throws NamingException{

       Hashtable<Object, Object> env = new Hashtable<Object, Object>();
        // WebLogic Server 10.x connection details
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");

        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://127.0.0.1:7001");

        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "dream");

        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "dream123");

        Context ic =  new InitialContext(env);

        MetamodelService metamodelService = (MetamodelService) ic.lookup("MetamodelContentService#com.evision.metamodel.services.MetamodelService");
        Euser user = metamodelService.findEuserByUserName("aaaaa@tata.ca");

        System.out.println(user.getFirstName());

    };  

   @GET
   @Produces("application/json")
   @Path("requete2")
public  String test2() {

     return "hello";

 }
}
```

when I am trying to call this function in my clients (MetamodelService metamodelService = (MetamodelService) ic.lookup("MetamodelContentService#com.metamodel.services.MetamodelService");)
i have that problem :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(PortableRemoteObject.java:262)
    at javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(PortableRemoteObject.java:153)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.readObject(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:215)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:991)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1866)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1964)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1888)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    at weblogic.utils.io.ChunkedObjectInputStream.readObject(ChunkedObjectInputStream.java:197)
    at weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevInputStream.readObject(MsgAbbrevInputStream.java:564)
    at weblogic.utils.io.ChunkedObjectInputStream.readObject(ChunkedObjectInputStream.java:193)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.ObjectIO.readObject(ObjectIO.java:62)
    at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.unmarshalReturn(ResponseImpl.java:240)
    at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:348)
    at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:259)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode_1030_WLStub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:392)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:380)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at service.GestionPersonnel.test(GestionPersonnel.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.evision.metamodel.services.impl.MetamodelContentService_jkkjlc_MetamodelServiceImpl_1032_WLStub cannot be cast to org.omg.CORBA.Object
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(PortableRemoteObject.java:245)
    ... 70 more
```

thanks for your reponses :)

Comment: What is your WLS version? Any error/exception at the WLS side?

Comment: weblogic 10, and i dont have any error/exception at the WLS side

Comment: the program work fine in application java , but when i use the remote ejb in web application a have the problem above

Comment: what is application java? You mean the code works fine in a standalone java application? WLS many versions started with 10. WLS 10.3, WLS 10.3.6, etc. Can you be more specific?

Comment: i have some service rest in glassfish sever that needs services   which exist  in the server(WLS) side , and i can't acces to the ejb remote !!!!!!